# Clear Textbox in Tab Control vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, tabcontrol

- I have a tab control that contains 3 tab pages.
- Each tab page contains a Group Box.
- Each Group box contains different controls.

What I want to happen is that when a user clicks on button, all Text-Boxes in all Tab Pages are cleared.

I used this code :

```
    For Each page As TabPage In TB_Emp.TabPages
        For Each ctl As Control In page.Controls
            If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
                ctl.Text = ""
            End If
            If TypeOf ctl Is ComboBox Then
                ctl.Text = ""
            End If
            If ctl.HasChildren Then
                For Each thing As Control In ctl.Controls
                    If TypeOf thing Is TextBox Then
                        thing.Text = ""
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

But it's only working on the first tab page, I want to apply this code on all Tab Control Pages

Comment: That should work.  There must be something else going on here that you might not be showing or telling us.

Comment: If these controls are in groupbox's your not accounting them. A recursive function would suit best for you...

Comment: no it's win application form

Answer (score -1):

Try looping over the controls in the .TabPages collection instead:

```
Dim tp as TabPage

For Each tp in Tabs.TabPages

For Each ctrl In tp.Controls

'Check for textbox etc.

Next

Next
```

Hope it helps

also you can use this [LINK](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/58a37932-dc26-4a67-acfe-4ad96f57b082/clearing-all-textboxes-on-a-tabpage)

Try this

```
 foreach (Control c in tabPage1.Controls)
            {
                if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                {
                    c.Text = string.Empty;
                }
            }
```

Comment: This is just a (bad) reiteration of what the OP has already posted.

Comment: i tried this solution but the same situation only working on the first Tab-Page , but i found something weird when i selected the last Tab-Page  and click on the button the Code worked on all pages perfectly !!